# Sed and renaming files

Tags: ubuntu, sed, renaming

I have a bulk of files in a directory, each one with different name and different length

Kind of Physician ... Class 218 (1080p_30fps_H264-128kbit_AAC).mp4
Another type of ... Class 223 (1080p_30fps_H264-128kbit_AAC).mp4
etc

I want to sort just "Class 218" "Class 1" etc and rename those files
Could you guys help me using sed ?

Comment: 1. Sed is not the best tool for bulk renaming files. 2. You should show a) the full file names and b) what they should be called afterwards. 3. There are many questions about file renaming already, are you sure this is a unique problem not asked about previously?

Comment: So if you remove everything except "Class" followed by 1 or more digits, you'd be good.

Comment: Hi Benjamin ! Iḿ new in sed , I was searching in stackoverflow and found a sample with sed. But I was not able to do it with the samples that I got, so I asked ok ?

Comment: Thank's Mark ! Sounds good.

Comment: Already did it ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Perl `rename` script. So, in this specific case, I would capture *"Class"* followed by one or more spaces and one or more digits as my capture group and then rename files with that whilst retaining the same extension:

```
rename --dry-run 's/.*(Class\s+\d+).*/$1.mp4/' *mp4
```

**Sample Output**

```
'Another type of ... Class 223 (1080p_30fps_H264-128kbit_AAC).mp4' would be renamed to 'Class 223.mp4'
'Kind of Physician something Class 218 (1080p_30fps_H264-128kbit_AAC).mp4' would be renamed to 'Class 218.mp4'
```

If that looks good, remove the `--dry-run` and run again for real.

Note that in the regex:

- `.*` means any character or digit repeated any number of times,
- `/s+` means any type of space (tab or space) occurring at least once and possibly more than once,
- `/d+` means any digit (0-9) occurring at least once and possibly more than once,
- `(...)` means capture everything inside the parentheses,
- `$1` means replace with the first thing previously captured in parentheses.

Comment: Thank you very much , I remove --dry -run (didn't ran). Now I 'll study what is the meaning of those parameters. Thank you very much !